# vector generation by linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have 4 vectors in $R^3$ given as: $v1=(-1,2,0), v2=(3,1,2), v3=(4,-1,0), v4=(0,1,-1)$. I have to show that the vector $v= (5,6,0)$ can be generated by a linear combination of this vector.
let the linear combination be $c1v1+c2v2+c3v3=(5,6,0)$ where scalers $c1,c2,c3$ are any real number.if we equate the co-ordinates of the vectors we get the linear system:
$$-c1+3c2+4c3=5\\
2c1+c2-c3+c4=6\\
2c2-c4=0$$
so we see there are 1 free variable in this system.so the linear combination is undefined.
but theoretically it is possible to generate a vector from one definite linear combination of 4 vectors in in $R^3$.so how can we get the linear combination that generates vector v?

Comment: Undefined doesn't matter as long as there is at least one.

Comment: The obvious two to pick are $v_1,v_3$ since they have last coordinate $0$. Taking $av_1+bv_3$ we find $a=\frac{29}{7},b=\frac{16}{7}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See at first  the thing  is that R^3 has atmost three linearly independent vectors. So its better that if you can find at first which three of them are linearly independent ,then it shall be easy to find the linear combination.

Comment: but one free variable remains and other three are well defined.so for each value of the free variable shouldn't we get different linear combinations and different result vector v?

Comment: I got my answer.thanks chirantan